# Bootstrap 4 multiple child divs of column to fill the height 100%

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, flexbox, bootstrap-4

In the following example is there a bootstrap way of making the div with id "second" fit inside its parent container and not overflow when given `h-100` class? A hacky way I used was applying `overflow:hidden` to the parent container of `#second` div and it does the job for my specific case but would this be called an elegant solution in this scenario?

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 bg-dark">
            <div id="first">
                <h5 class="text-white">some title</h5>
            </div>
            <div id="second" class="h-100 bg-success">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 bg-danger">
            <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/540x400"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/pSVIlOETpB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sure, just make the containing `col-6` display:flex, flex-direction:column by using `d-flex flex-column` classes on it...

https://www.codeply.com/go/5YiBkLo0qO

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-6 bg-dark d-flex flex-column">
            <div id="first">
                <h5 class="text-white">some title</h5>
            </div>
            <div id="second" class="h-100 bg-success">

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-6 bg-danger">
            <a href="https://placeholder.com"><img src="http://via.placeholder.com/540x400"></a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```